# Oozie : Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.1

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

I am getting error when i am trying to build oozie.
Hadoop version : Hadoop 2.4.0
JDK : 1.8

I used this command to run oozie : 
./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests

Running above code gives me following error : 
I am not sure what wrong is going on.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [3.519s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [1:27.702s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [3.264s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [0.492s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [0.737s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [7.398s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [0.762s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [0.472s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ............ SUCCESS [5.743s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 Test ....... SUCCESS [0.717s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ..... SUCCESS [0.433s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [6.454s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [1.008s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ........................... SUCCESS [1.464s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1 ........... SUCCESS [10.452s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.6.0.oozie-4.0.1 ........... SUCCESS [48.119s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ........................ SUCCESS [18.486s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... FAILURE [1:12.599s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:32.358s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jun 21 19:56:11 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/101M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:230)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:204)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:427)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-sharelib-oozie

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I struck with the same issue while trying oozie 4.0.1. 
Instead I tried working on oozie 4.0.0. oozie 4.0.0 also failed at "..SNAPSHOT.oozie-4.0.0".
then i followed [these](http://grepalex.com/2014/02/16/oozie-and-hadoop-2.2/) instructions and working fine.
I think some repositories of oozie-4.0.1 + hadoop-2.4.0 are missing .